# How to convert with Python this hex to its decoded output?

Tags: python, hex

I'm trying to convert the following (that seems to be an HEX) with Python with its decoded output:

I want to convert this:

[image]

To this:
[image]

How to do this?

This is the string:

```
0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000040000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000080000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000006331b7e000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000c0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000474657374000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000007566963746f727900000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

Comment: can you post the string please?

Comment: Sure, I just updated the question with the string

Comment: What do you mean by "decoded output"? You can easily convert the hex string into a single number, but then what? Maybe you need to interpret the hex string as bytes instead? What is the structure of the resulting bytes?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice the decoded output is the one shown in the second screenshot, I'm trying to convert the Hex to that decoded output, but I can not figure out how? Those are screenshot from Etherscan logs.

Comment: Yes, you showed the output, but it is still unclear how you should get that output from the hex input. I assume that you need to first convert the hex into bytes, but then what bytes determine which part of the output?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice, that's what i'm trying to resolve. Any suggestion? What is that number to begin with? if is a simple hexdecimal?

Comment: The format of the bytes is defined by a protocol. Is this raw Ethernet data? Or is it something else? I'm not familiar with Etherscan, so I don't know what that is.

Comment: OIC...after googling Etherscan, I see that it is data from the Ethereum blockchain. You will need to research more about Ethereum to learn its structure.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice this is the link to the Etherscan Ropsten page: https://ropsten.etherscan.io/tx/0xa14d69ce741581687988fa2e2e40f70d9871795c25de147a9ee87149422ef527#eventlog

Comment: Yes, you will need to find the documentation for Ethereum to learn about the structure of that binary data. I assume that the `uint256` parts are 256 bits or 32 bytes. I don't know how long the `string` parts are, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to convert the hex into a bytearray:

```
hex = 0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000040000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000080000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000006331b7e000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000c0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000474657374000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000007566963746f727900000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
b = bytearray.fromhex(hex).decode()
```

Then you will need to determine the layout of the bytes. For example, an `unit256` is probably 32 bytes which is 64 hex digits:

```
a = b[:64]
print(int.from_bytes(a, "big"))
```

Here I assume the bytes are in big-endian. If they are instead little-endian, you can use `"little"` instead of `"big"`. You will need to learn about so-called "endianness" to understand this better.

You can get the other `uint256` in a similar way.

As for the strings, I don't know what their length is. You will have to research the format for Ethereum blockchain data. Once you determine the length, you can use a similar technique to get the bytes for each string and then decode it into characters.

Answer (score 1):

Just use the inbuilt decode function in Python:

```
str="0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000040000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000080000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000006331b7e000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000c0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000474657374000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000007566963746f727900000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000" #YOUR HEX
str.decode("hex")
```

Alternatively, if that does not work, you can use:
`bytearray.fromhex(str).decode()`